# C++ Why is my swap function not being called?

Tags: c++

Overview: I am trying to sort these objects of arrays by distance and then print the distance to the console in order from shortest to longest. I am using the Leg class to store the strings as character pointers and the distance as a double. I have overloaded the < operator but I have a sort that is using a swap but my build is failing. This is my first time using the overload operator so I am still new to how it works. I feel like I am going in the right direction. Any feedback would be appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Leg {
    
    const char* const startingCity;
    const char* const endingCity;
    const double distance;
    
public:
    Leg(const char* const, const char* const, const double);
    bool operator<(const Leg&); //for swap
    double getDistance() const {return distance;};
    void output(ostream&) const;
};

int main () {
    
    Leg a[] =
    {
        Leg("Antioch", "Brentwood", 6.9),
        Leg("Pittsburg", "Elk Grove", 40.1),
        Leg("Benicia", "Martinez", 2.9),
        Leg("Napa", "Fairfield", 13.3),
        Leg("Brentwood", "Novato", 48.3),
        Leg("Fremont", "Concord", 29.8),
        Leg("San Pablo", "San Rafael", 11.8),
        Leg("Walnut Creek", "Dixon", 39.7),
        Leg("Santa Rosa", "Napa", 26.4),
        Leg("Daly City", "Alameda", 20.2),
        Leg("San Leandro", "Dublin", 20.3),
        Leg("Modesto", "Antioch", 52.5),
        Leg("Pleasanton", "San Ramon", 10.6),
        Leg("Lafayette", "Livermore", 25.4),
        Leg("Vacaville", "San Francisco", 77.2),
        Leg("Hayward", "Danville", 11.9),
        Leg("Berkeley", "Richmond", 10.1),
        Leg("Oakland", "Oakley", 33.3),
        Leg("Lodi", "Mountain View", 66.2),
        Leg("Antioch", "San Jose", 76.9),
        Leg("Milpitas", "Pacifica", 54.9),
        Leg("Burlingame", "Petaluma", 73.8),
        Leg("Redwood City", "San Bruno", 19.2),
        Leg("San Mateo", "Brentwood", 42.6),
        Leg("Union City", "Ripon", 83.0 ),
        Leg("Sunnyvale", "Tracy", 41.7),
        Leg("Rohnert Park", "Benicia", 36.9),
        Leg("Foster City", "Pittsburg", 6.9),
        Leg("Danville", "Manteca", 43.2),
        Leg("Antioch", "Stockton", 28.4),
        Leg("San Francisco", "Oakland", 9.1),
        Leg("Antioch", "Walnut Creek", 15.8),
        Leg("Vallejo", "Berkeley", 16.2),
        Leg("San Ramon", "Walnut Creek", 9.9),
        Leg("Tracy", "Fremont", 33.6),
        Leg("Martinez", "Concord", 6.7),
        Leg("Lafayette", "Daly City", 22.8),
        Leg("Livermore", "Petaluma", 60.6),
        Leg("Galt", "Mountain View",72.5),
        Leg("Pleasant Hill", "Richmond", 15.8)
        
    };
    
    const int SIZE = (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
            if(a[j].getDistance() < a[i].getDistance())
                swap(a[i], a[j]); //error is occurring on this line
    
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        a[i].output(cout);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Leg::Leg(const char* const start, const char* const end, const double dist) //constructor
:startingCity(start), endingCity(end), distance(dist)
{
    
}

void Leg::output(ostream& out) const //output function
{
    out << "Leg: " << startingCity << " to " << endingCity << ", " << distance << " miles." << endl;
}

bool Leg::operator<(const Leg& rhs)
{
    return distance < rhs.getDistance();
}
```

Comment: First, post the exact error message.  Second, naming your array as `a` makes the code hard to read, let alone susceptible to bugs due to possible or future name clashes.  Give your variables more descriptive names.

Comment: I believe it's using the Standard swap, but there is no overload provided for `Leg`. Switching to `std::string` would go a long way to fixing this, else you have add Rule of 5 functions.

Comment: `bool operator<(const Leg&); //for swap` -- Why are you not simply using `std::sort`, i.e. `std::sort(a, a + SIZE);`?

Comment: Error is: No matching function call to 'swap'.

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you think providing `operator<` should matter for `swap`? You need to provide a `swap` that works for `Leg` anyway.

Comment: `if(a[j].getDistance() < a[i].getDistance())` -- I think you missed the point of why you overloaded `<`.  That should simply be `if (a[j] < a[i])`

Comment: After looking closer, `std::sort` with a lambda is the much better way to go about this. `operator<()` implies a canonical way to sort `Leg` objects. Judging by the data in `Leg`, that's probably not the case.

Comment: I need to incorporate the use of an assignment operator function. And I see I do not need the getDistance() because the assignment operator function is doing that for me, thank you. However my build is still failing from that swap error I mentioned.

Comment: Assignment won't work with all your data being `const`. Getters are not assignment. I recommend stepping back, collecting yourself, and coming back fresh.

Comment: Tip: Get out of the habit of using C-style arrays and embrace `std::vector`, which you can easily pass by reference which will include important size information.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Leg` class is neither move-constructible nor move-assignable due to `const` members. So it can't be [swapped](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Drop the `const` requirement from its members and it'll get an implicit move-constructor and assignment operator and `std::swap` will pick those up.

```
class Leg {
    const char* startingCity;
    const char* endingCity;
    double distance;
    . . .
```

Final note: `operator <` has no effect on `swap`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that *sorting* is an algorithm that needs two things to work: a comparison between 2 elements of the range, and a way to move elements around. The first you get with `operator<`. In your case, you are manually comparing 2 `Leg`s with:

```
if(a[j].getDistance() < a[i].getDistance())
```

so you don't need an `operator<`. Since you have provided one, you can do:

```
if(a[j] < a[i])
```

The second requirement is a way to move elements around, which is typically done by *swapping* elements around. You need to provide a way to do that, since `std::swap` is not going to do that for you, since `Leg` is neither move-constructible or move-assignable due to the `const` members.

```
void swap(Leg const &, Leg const &);
```

Providing `operator<` is not going to give you `swap` or vice versa. You need to provide both yourself.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation!

Comment: @Jeremiah No problem :) If the answers solve your problem, you can go ahead and accept one of them. Make sure to pick the answer that you find the most useful.

Answer (score 2):

> C++ Why is my swap function not being called?

You haven't defined a swap function. As such, there is no "your swap function" that could be called.

Solution: Either define the function that you call, or simply call the generic `std::swap` instead... that is, if your class could be made swappable in the first place. It cannot be, because it has const members. Solution to the secondary problem: Make the members non-const.

P.S. There is no need to define a naïve sorting function. The standard library provides a generic `std::sort`.

P.P.S There is no need to use the complex `const int SIZE = (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]));`. You can use `std::size(a)` instead.

P.P.P.S There is no need for a hand written loop `for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`. A range-for would be simpler.

Comment: Thank you appreciate the feedback and tips!

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the issue is that you never wrote a swap function. There is `std::swap`, and it is possible to overload it for your class, which you didn't do.

But if you want smaller fixes, your comparison doesn't need to `.getDistance()`; you wrote `operator<()` to directly compare two `Leg`s.

You would then need to write a swap function for your class, which might also mean removing all the `const`s around your data members. Private class data doesn't need to be marked `const` as a matter of course; it's already encapsulated. But then again, `Leg` might be better off as a `struct` anyway.

But a couple different tweaks result in less work done and the same result:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
// #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

class Leg {
  std::string startingCity;
  std::string endingCity;
  double distance;

 public:
  Leg(std::string start, std::string end, double dist);
  // bool operator<(const Leg&);  // for swap
  double getDistance() const { return distance; };
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const Leg& leg);
};

int main() {
  Leg a[] = {Leg("Antioch", "Brentwood", 6.9),
             Leg("Pittsburg", "Elk Grove", 40.1),
             Leg("Benicia", "Martinez", 2.9),
             Leg("Napa", "Fairfield", 13.3),
             Leg("Brentwood", "Novato", 48.3),
             Leg("Fremont", "Concord", 29.8),
             Leg("San Pablo", "San Rafael", 11.8),
             Leg("Walnut Creek", "Dixon", 39.7),
             Leg("Santa Rosa", "Napa", 26.4),
             Leg("Daly City", "Alameda", 20.2),
             Leg("San Leandro", "Dublin", 20.3),
             Leg("Modesto", "Antioch", 52.5),
             Leg("Pleasanton", "San Ramon", 10.6),
             Leg("Lafayette", "Livermore", 25.4),
             Leg("Vacaville", "San Francisco", 77.2),
             Leg("Hayward", "Danville", 11.9),
             Leg("Berkeley", "Richmond", 10.1),
             Leg("Oakland", "Oakley", 33.3),
             Leg("Lodi", "Mountain View", 66.2),
             Leg("Antioch", "San Jose", 76.9),
             Leg("Milpitas", "Pacifica", 54.9),
             Leg("Burlingame", "Petaluma", 73.8),
             Leg("Redwood City", "San Bruno", 19.2),
             Leg("San Mateo", "Brentwood", 42.6),
             Leg("Union City", "Ripon", 83.0),
             Leg("Sunnyvale", "Tracy", 41.7),
             Leg("Rohnert Park", "Benicia", 36.9),
             Leg("Foster City", "Pittsburg", 6.9),
             Leg("Danville", "Manteca", 43.2),
             Leg("Antioch", "Stockton", 28.4),
             Leg("San Francisco", "Oakland", 9.1),
             Leg("Antioch", "Walnut Creek", 15.8),
             Leg("Vallejo", "Berkeley", 16.2),
             Leg("San Ramon", "Walnut Creek", 9.9),
             Leg("Tracy", "Fremont", 33.6),
             Leg("Martinez", "Concord", 6.7),
             Leg("Lafayette", "Daly City", 22.8),
             Leg("Livermore", "Petaluma", 60.6),
             Leg("Galt", "Mountain View", 72.5),
             Leg("Pleasant Hill", "Richmond", 15.8)

  };

  std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
            [](Leg a, Leg b) { return a.getDistance() < b.getDistance(); });

  for (auto i : a) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}

Leg::Leg(std::string start, std::string end, double dist)
    : startingCity(start), endingCity(end), distance(dist) {}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const Leg& leg) {
  return sout << "Leg: " << leg.startingCity << " to " << leg.endingCity << ", "
              << leg.distance << " miles.";
}
```

Some of the changes I've made are that swapped out your C-strings with `std::string`s. I removed your `operator<()`. By including that, you're saying that there is a definitive way to sort your objects. That's likely not the case at all. I also changed your `output()` function to `operator<<()`. This allows your class to be idiomatically printed.

Your bubble sort has been replaced with `std::sort` and a lambda that tells `std::sort` how to arrange the `Leg`s.

Generally I would say that you want to write your classes in such a way that they are able to integrate smoothly with the Standard Library. `std::sort` is much more efficient than a basic bubble sort, and being able to print your objects directly with `std::cout` is much nicer (Note that as written, you can now write your objects using any outstream).